# How to pass parameter from an action class to a JSP with Struts2?

Tags: struts2

I'll try to explain my question with an example. I'm making a login page. I pass a username and password from the index-page to an action class for verification. If everything's okay, then using the strus.xml, I open a new JSP. Now, I wan't to display the name of the user who just logged in on the new JSP. Here's an example struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <package name="login" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="tryLogin" class="action.LoginAction">
            <result name="success" >/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="login">/login.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Comment: i think u should go through the ModelDriven interface provided by Struts2 it is for these perpose only.

Answer (score 1):

**1** Just create "userLogin" variable in your action class with public `getter` and `setter`

```
public LoginAction extends ActionSupport {

  private String userLogin;

  public String execute{
    ... some code.....
  }

  public String getUserLogin(){
    return userLogin;
  }

  public void setUserLogin(String login){
    this.userLogin= login;
  }
}
```

Struts2 ParametersInterceptor will get the parameter value from request and set it to action parameer automaticly.

2 To read this parameter in the action result jsp page just use some struts tags

```
  <s:property value="userLogin"/>, 
  <s:textfield name="userLogin"/>,
```

etc..

Comment: I have variables in my action class. To be more precise, I have an object with variables, getters and setters. Do I need to add something else to my struts.xml?

Comment: No there is nothing to add